# Máscara de porcentagem

Tags: javascript, html5

Como posso fazer uma máscara de porcentagem, onde o usuário digita um número em porcento num input-text, o número pode ser no máximo 100%, daí se por exemplo o usuário digitar 30% no primeiro input, ele já não pode digitar mais de 70% no segundo input, daí digita 20% no segundo, no terceiro já não pode digitar mais de 50%. Também se possível fazer aparecer o símbolo da porcentagem no final do número.

Comment: Com JS e HTML5, como colocou nas tags, já é possível. O que já tentou fazer e qual foi a dificuldade?

Comment: Eu coloquei apenas os input, deixando os números para o usuário escolher livremente, mas gostaria de colocar uma máscara para fechar corretamente em 100% no total. Eu sei que dá pra fazer com js, mas conheço bem pouco de JS, tô no nível "acende-lampada/apaga-lâmpada".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lógica funciona assim, levando em consideração que são 3 usuários:
Se o usuário A estiver adicionando valor, ele terá que somar o valor já existente do B e do C para ver o que sobra pra ele.
Se for o B vai somar o A e C.
E se for o C vai somar o A e o B.

Agora se for um único usuário com três campos input usaremos apenas JAVASCRIPT.

Só não vai funcionar no *Internet Explorer* por que usei `input` do tipo `number` pra alterar o atributo `MAX` real de cada campo:

```js
function distribuirPercent(t){
   var myform = document.forms.porcentagem;
   var lmt;
   var n = t.name;
   /* Pré limitação por segurança */
   myform.campo_a.max = myform.campo_a.value;
   myform.campo_b.max = myform.campo_b.value;
   myform.campo_c.max = myform.campo_c.value;
   /* ---------------------------------------------*/

   /* Transformar campos em números para operações */
   var a = parseInt(myform.campo_a.value);
   var b = parseInt(myform.campo_b.value);
   var c = parseInt(myform.campo_c.value);
   /* ---------------------------------------------*/
   if(n == "campo_a"){
      lmt = b+c;
   }
   if(n == "campo_b"){
      lmt = a+c;
   }
   if(n == "campo_c"){
      lmt = a+b;
   }
   console.clear();
   console.log("Total dos outros 2: "+lmt);
   lmt = 100-lmt;
   console.log("Limite permitido: "+lmt);
   t.max = lmt;
}
```

```css
input[type=number] {
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
-moz-appearance: textfield;
    appearance: textfield;
    margin: 0;
    border: solid 0px #fff;
    width: 20px;
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<form name="porcentagem">
<label><input type="number" name="campo_a" min="0" max="100" value="0" onfocus="distribuirPercent(this)" size="3" />%</label><br />
<label><input type="number" name="campo_b" min="0" max="100" value="0" onfocus="distribuirPercent(this)" size="3" />%</label><br />
<label><input type="number" name="campo_c" min="0" max="100" value="0" onfocus="distribuirPercent(this)" size="3" />%</label>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<input>` elementos do tipo "range" deixa o usuário especificar um valor numerico que não deve ser inferior a um determinado valor, e não mais do que um valor máximo especificado. O valor preciso, no entanto, não é considerado importante. Este geralmente é representado por um controle deslizante ou o mesmo tipo de controle de "number" input. Como este tipo de elemento é impreciso, não deve ser usado a menos que o valor exato do controle não seja importante.

```
<input type="range">
```

[Leia mais](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/range)

Answer (score 0):

Um forma de fazer isso é somando tudo à medida que vai digitando. Se a soma ultrapassar 100, o campo digitado é *limpado* para que se possa digitar um valor válido:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
   let els = document.querySelectorAll(".inps"),
   calc = (i) => {
      let ttl = 0,
      thisval = i.target.value;

      for(let x=0; x<els.length; x++){
         ttl += Number(els[x].value.replace(",",".").replace("%",""));
         if(ttl > 100){
            i.target.value = '';
         }
      }
      
      if(thisval.indexOf("%") == -1) i.target.value += "%";

      i.target.selectionStart = i.target.selectionEnd = thisval.replace("%","").length;
   }

   for(let x=0; x<els.length; x++){
      els[x].addEventListener("input", calc);
   }
});
```

```html
<input maxlength="3" type="text" class="inps">
<br>
<input maxlength="3" type="text" class="inps">
<br>
<input maxlength="3" type="text" class="inps">
```